# Effect of clicking back on a browser on the context variables

Tags: django

Suppose I have two templates, A and B. When template A loads, it is sent some context variables. Template A also contains a button that transfers the user to template B, via a view function.

My question is: If the user goes from template A to template B, but then clicks the "back" button on the browser, such that template A loads, do the context variables still remain in memory with template A? Or will the context variables originally sent to template A be lost forever?

Comment: of course they remain the same...

Answer (score 1):

What you describe here:

> clicks the "back" button on the browser, such that template A loads

does not happen. When you click the back button, pages do *not* load again. The browser simply redisplays what it has in its cache. Nothing is reloaded, and neither templates nor context variables come into it at all.